# HttpContext is null asp net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I am trying to use HttpContextAccessor on my custom class(BLL class) and while i succesfully initializes the ContextAccessor meantime HttpContext itself is null.

Code in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserPermissionConfig, UserPermisionConfig>();


builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

var setUserPermission = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IUserPermissionConfig>();
setUserPermission.SetUserPermissionsSession(UserConstants.SYSTEM_ID);
```

UserPermisionConfig component code

```
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserPermisionConfig( IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _permisionServiceClient = new PermissionServiceClient();

        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new Exception("Http context accessor is null.");
    }

    public async Task SetUserPermissionsSession(int systemId)
    {
        string userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.
             User.Identity.Name; //here httpcontext is alway null
        UserPermissionsModel userPermissionModel = await GetUserPermission(systemId, userName);

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Set(UserConstants.SESSION_USER_PERMISSIOS, ByteArrayExtensions.ToByteArray(userPermissionModel));
    }
```

Any help ?

Comment: How is IUserPermissionConfig registered? When are you requesting an instance of it?

Comment: IHttpContextAccessor Is only valid in the scope of an asp.net core request

Comment: builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserPermissionConfig, UserPermisionConfig>();

Comment: There aren't that many _good_ reasons for ever using `IHttpContextAccessor` (it's a poorly-designed service and [Microsoft admits as much](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor)) - why not change `SetUserPermissionsSession` to add a `ClaimsIdentity` parameter instead?

Comment: i edited code for better understanding

Comment: Dai can you suggest that in code ? I mean as a full answer ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#httpcontext-access-from-a-background-thread)

just as mentioned in the document:

**HttpContext isn't thread-safe. Reading or writing properties of the HttpContext outside of processing a request can result in a NullReferenceException.**

In Asp.net if you call httpcontext directly in `Application_Start()` method in global.asax.cs,you would get the similar error

If your codes was in your HttpModule in Asp.net ,check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-7.0#migrating-module-code-to-middleware) to learn how to migrate module codes to middleware

And I tried as below:

```
public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;       
        private readonly IUserPermisionConfig _config;


        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,  IUserPermisionConfig config)
        {
            
            
            _next = next;

            _config = config;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {

            _config.SetUserPermissionsSession(5);

           await _next(context);
        }
    }


    public interface IUserPermisionConfig
    {
        Task SetUserPermissionsSession(int systemId); 
    }
    public class UserPermisionConfig : IUserPermisionConfig
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
        public UserPermisionConfig(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }
        public  Task SetUserPermissionsSession(int systemId)
        {
            var httpcontext = _accessor.HttpContext;
            var user = httpcontext.User.Identity?.Name;
            httpcontext.Session.SetString("Somekey", systemId.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Regist the services:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserPermisionConfig, UserPermisionConfig>();
// The two following services are required to use session in asp.net core 
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();
```

call the middleware in the pipeline :

```
.....

app.UseSession();

app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
.....
```

it works well in my case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like you are trying to access the HTTP context directly from `Program.cs`.  This is not how it works.

The HTTP context is only avialable during an incoming HTTP request.

Your `IUserPermissionConfig` service must be called from the ASP.net pipeline somewhere (controller, filter, middleware).

Comment: in old asp net mvc it was possible to call httpcontext from global.asax.cs...thanks anyway