# IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is null WebForms

Tags: .net-core, httpcontext, .net-4.8

I've been trying to use IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext to read the current HttpContext when I call an API from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET Core.

I've put added it into the service:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor()
services.AddTransient<IService, Service>();
```

and I get the HttpContextAccessor in the class but the HttpContext is always null:

Page:

```
Private ReadOnly service As IService
Private httpContextAccessor As Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor
Public Sub New(ByVal service As IService, ..., httpContextAccessor As IHttpContextAccessor)
    Me.service = service
    ...
    Me.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor'<-- in debug mode I can see that HttpContext is null here also
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Public Async Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Dim httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext              '<--this is null
        Dim results = await service.Method()
    End Sub
```

Services:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

public Service(..., IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,...)
{
    this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor; //<-- in debug mode I can see that HttpContext is null here also
}

public async Task<List<ModelDTO>> Method()
{
    var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext; //<-- Also null here.
    ...
}
```

I would have passed it through from the page to the services if it wasn't null there. I've read a few things about it but can't figure this out.

For example

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74441147) - I've tried changing the button so that it wasn't Async and would have expected the httpContext to be populated before going into the Method but it wasn't.

I've also seen some of the suggestions on how to implement IHttpContextAccessor and I think I've done it correctly by copying it.